# ImportError: No module named xml.dom.minidom

Tags: python, xml

I try to export xml.dom to my python program.

```
from xml.dom import minidom
```

But when i run the code, i got this error:

```
import xml.dom.minidom
ImportError: No module named xml.dom.minidom
```

This happened before when i rename my file to xml.py, but it's clear when i change name to other. But this is another problem i got. i didn't rename my file. It happened after i run apt-get update and apt-get upgrade ubuntu.

What's wrong?

Comment: Did you remove the `xml.pyc` that would have been created if you imported your `xml.py` file? If you don't remove the `pyc` file, `import xml` may still be loading the bogus `xml` module.

Comment: @unutbu yes, i did. there's no error after that. i got error when i update my ubuntu. i don't know that the problem exist because i update my ubuntu or not

Comment: In a Python interpreter type `import xml; xml.__file__`. What path do you see?

Comment: @unutbu File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>; ImportError: No module named xml

Comment: In a terminal, what does `which python` return?

Comment: @unutbu File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named xml

Comment: when i do locate minidom.py :/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/minidom.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/minidom.pyc
/usr/lib/python3.4/xml/dom/minidom.py

Comment: @unutbu there is python 3.4. is it the problem?

Comment: please do `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: @warvariuc ['/home/dionajie/Documents/python/myc45', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode']

Comment: try `import sys; sys.path.pop(0); import xml; print(repr(xml))`

Comment: @warvariuc ImportError: No module named xml

Comment: Are you sure that `which python` gave `<stdin>", line 1, in <module> ImportError: No module named xml`?

Comment: @warvariuc sorry. it returns /usr/bin/python

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98482/discussion-between-warvariuc-and-dionajie).

Answer (score 2):

did you created any file named as `xml.py`? that may be the issue. rename it will solve the Issue